# Making a list of dictionaries from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm a Python newbie. As a fun exercise, I thought I would create a list of dictionaries from a list of tuples. Little did I know I would bang my head against the wall for hours.

```
boys = [("Joe", 7, 125), ("Sam", 8, 130), ("Jake", 9, 225)]
keys = ("Name","Height","Weight")
boyz = []
for x in boys:
    z = dict(zip(keys,boys[x]))
    boyz.append(z)
print(boyz)
```

When the x in "boys[x]" is replaced with a integer, it works great, but replacing it with a variable within the for loop won't work. WHY?? I'd love an answer to that specifically. But also if there's a more concise to write this whole thing, please let me know.

Comment: What is your change? What is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration of the `for x in boys` loop, `x` will be the value of the next tuple in the list. It is not an integer you can use as an index. Use `x` instead of `boys[x]` in the `zip` to get the result you want.

```
for x in boys:
    z = dict(zip(keys,x))
    boyz.append(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `boys[x]` instead of `x`.

This raises the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Here is your edited code:

```
boys = [("Joe", 7, 125), ("Sam", 8, 130), ("Jake", 9, 225)]
keys = ("Name","Height","Weight")
boyz = []
for x in boys:
    z = dict(zip(keys,x))
    boyz.append(z)

print(boyz)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> boys = [("Joe", 7, 125), ("Sam", 8, 130), ("Jake", 9, 225)]
>>> keys = ("Name","Height","Weight")
>>> boyz = []
>>> for x in boys:
...     z = dict(zip(keys,x))
...     boyz.append(z)
... 
>>> print(boyz)
[{'Name': 'Joe', 'Weight': 125, 'Height': 7}, {'Name': 'Sam', 'Weight': 130, 'Height': 8}, {'Name': 'Jake', 'Weight': 225, 'Height': 9}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

boys is a list. lists only support indices that are integers but you're passing in a tuple. You'll want to use x as the tuple.

Ultimately, your goal is to get an iterable of keys and values to pass in to zip.

```
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise version, as you asked, can be achieved using list comprehension.

```
boyz = [dict(zip(keys, boy)) for boy in boys]
```

Generally, when you see the pattern of creating an empty list, iterating over some iterable and appending its values after map / filtering, you can use a list comprehension instead.

This:

```
new_list = []
for item in iterable:
    if condition(item):
        new_value = mapping(item)
        new_list.append(new_value)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
new_list = [mapping(item) for item in iterable if condition(item)]
```